# Prolog: Find the number of nodes for levels in binary tree

Tags: prolog

I should find the width of a binary tree, so the maximum amount of nodes in the same level.

I should define: `width_tree(Tree, Result)`.

I have tried, but I don't understand how to count the nodes in the same level.
I have thought to consider two predicate one for the left side and one for the right side like:

```
width_tree([Node, Left, Rigth], Result):-
  width_tree(Left, 0, Result),
  width_tree(Rigth, 0, Result).
```

but I don't understand how can I consider how many nodes there are.

How can I do?

This is the tree:

```
[12, [8, [5, [2, nil, nil], nil],[11, nil, nil]], [65, [42, nil, nil], [99, nil, nil]]]
```

[image]

The result is 4, because at the third level there are 4 nodes (5, 11, 42, 99)

Comment: Prolog does depth first search by default. You need breadth first search. In Prolog this is also done with `iterative deepening`. See: [Iterative Deepening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iterative-deepening+prolog) SO Prolog questions for ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by defining a predicate to **update a list of widths**:

```
% update_widths(+Widths, +Level, -NewWidths)

  update_widths([],            L, [w(L,1)]).
  update_widths([w(L0,W0)|R0], L, [w(L0,W1)|R0]) :- L0==L, !, W1 is W0 + 1.
  update_widths([w(L0,W0)|R0], L, [w(L0,W0)|R1]) :- L0\=L, update_widths(R0, L, R1).
```

Example:

```
?- update_widths([],1,A), update_widths(A,2,B), update_widths(B,2,C), update_widths(C,2,D).
A = [w(1, 1)],
B = [w(1, 1), w(2, 1)],
C = [w(1, 1), w(2, 2)],
D = [w(1, 1), w(2, 3)].
```

After that, you can define a predicate to **get a list of widths** for a given binary tree:

```
% get_widths(+Tree, +Level, +Widths, -NewWidths)

  get_widths(nil, _, Widths, Widths).
  get_widths([_,Left,Right], Level, Widths, NewWidths) :-
     NextLevel is Level + 1,
     update_widths(Widths, Level, Widths0),
     get_widths(Left,  NextLevel, Widths0, Widths1),
     get_widths(Right, NextLevel, Widths1, NewWidths).

% A tree

  tree([12,[8,[5,[2,nil,nil],nil],[11,nil,nil]],[65,[42,nil,nil],[99,nil,nil]]]).
```

Example:

```
?- tree(T), get_widths(T, 1, [], W).T = [12, [8, [5, [2, nil, nil], nil], [11, nil, nil]], [65, [42, nil, nil], [99, nil, nil]]],
W = [w(1, 1), w(2, 2), w(3, 4), w(4, 1)].
```

Then, you can define a predicate to find the **maximum width** in a list of widths:

```
% max_width(+Widths, -MaxWidth)

  max_width([w(_,MaxWidth)], MaxWidth).
  max_width([w(L1,W1),w(L2,W2)|Widths], MaxWidth) :-
     (   W1 > W2
     ->  max_width([w(L1,W1)|Widths], MaxWidth)
     ;   max_width([w(L2,W2)|Widths], MaxWidth) ).
```

Example:

```
?- tree(T), get_widths(T,1,[],W), max_width(W,M).
T = [12, [8, [5, [2, nil, nil], nil], [11, nil, nil]], [65, [42, nil, nil], [99, nil, nil]]],
W = [w(1, 1), w(2, 2), w(3, 4), w(4, 1)],
M = 4.
```

Finally, you can define the main predicate to get the **tree width**:

```
tree_width(Tree, Width) :-
   get_widths(Tree, 1, [], Widths),
   max_width(Widths, Width).
```

Example:

```
?- tree(T), tree_width(T,W).
T = [12, [8, [5, [2, nil, nil], nil], [11, nil, nil]], [65, [42, nil, nil], [99, nil, nil]]],
W = 4.
```

**Remark**: For the sake of clarity, I've chosen to represent pairs as `w(Level,Width)`. However, Prolog's convention is to represent such pairs as `Level-Width`.